# Where do I put my website php files in my virtual ubuntu server?

Tags: server, virtualbox, php, lamp, webserver

I am trying to create a website through my ubuntu. I also intend to host this website on my ubuntu. I am goign to use dreamweaver for my php files and then put those php files in my ubuntu server.

What I don't know is :

1. Where do I put these files in ubuntu ?
   (Assuming I have to create the files in ubuntu, how do I save them ? what commands do I use ? where do I save them?)

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, after installing apache2 the website root is located under:

```
/var/www/
```

or

```
/var/www/html/
```

(depending on the Ubuntu version you installed).

So, in order to test your php, you'll need to move them to that location and set the correct ownership. Again, with apache, the file owner should be the system user www-data. Asuming your file is called `yourfile.php` you'll use these commands:

```
sudo cp yourfile.php /var/www/html/
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/yourfile.php
```

Then, just open your browser and direct it to `http://localhost/yourfile.php` to see if it's working properly.